# Conditional return time of simple random walk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, $(S_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Call $\tau_k = \min\{t \in \mathbb{N}\, : \, \, S_t =k \}$, the *hitting time* of $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Call $\tau^* = \min\{t >0\, : \, \, S_t =0 \}$, the *return time* to the origin. Let $c<1$ be a positive constant.

Is there a way to compute the next formula explicitly?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} P ( \tau_k = j \, | \, \tau_k < \tau^*) \cdot c^{j-1}$$

Comment: For starters can you compute $P(\tau_k\lt\tau^*)$?

Comment: Yes, let's say we know that….

Comment: Perhaps a bound could be $\frac{P(\tau^* > j)}{P(\tau_j < \tau^*)}$, just using the bound $P(\tau_k < \tau^*) > P(\tau_j < \tau^*)$. But is $P(\tau^* > j)$ know exactly?

Comment: No, how do YOU compute THE EXACT VALUE of $P(\tau_k\lt\tau^*)$?

Comment: The first step must be right. Thus $P(\tau_k < \tau^*) = $p P(SRW starting from 1 reaches k before 0)$ and it comes from the gambler ruin problem.

Comment: This probability is $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{k}$ in case of $p = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2p - 1}{1 - (\frac{1 - p}{p})^k}$ in case of $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Rrrright. And now to your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have $\tau_k < \tau^*$, the first step of the walk must be in the positive direction.  So, we may as well start the walk at position $1$: let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $\ldots$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=-1)={1\over 2}$, let $T_n:=1+\sum_{1\le i\le n} X_i\ \ (n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0})$, and let $\mu_k:=\min \{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\mid T_n=k\}$.  We then want to compute 
$$
\sum_{k\ge 1} \mathbb{E}[c^{\mu_k}\mid \mu_k<\mu_0],
$$
where the $-1$ in the exponent has disappeared because we started the walk
at what was formerly time $1$.
Fix some $A>0$ and let $M_n:=c^n A^{T_n}$; if $A+A^{-1}=2/c$, $M_n$ will be a martingale.  Then, by the optional stopping theorem, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A=M_0&=& \mathbb{E}[M_{\min(\mu_k, \mu_0)}]\\
&=& \mathbb{P}(\mu_k<\mu_0) \mathbb{E}[c^{\mu_k}\mid \mu_k < \mu_0] A^k+ 
\mathbb{P}(\mu_k>\mu_0) \mathbb{E}[c^{\mu_0}\mid \mu_k > \mu_0]. \ \ (*)
\end{eqnarray*}
The equation $A+A^{-1}=2/c$ has two positive roots.  Let $A_0$ be the one greater than $1$; the other will then be $A_0^{-1}$.  Setting $A:=A_0$
and $A:=A_0^{-1}$ in $(*)$ then gives two linear equations.  Subtracting one
from the other and solving gives
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mu_k<\mu_0) \mathbb{E}[c^{\mu_k}\mid \mu_k < \mu_0]
= {A_0-A_0^{-1}\over A_0^k-A_0^{-k}}=
{1\over A_0^{k-1}+A_0^{k-3}+\cdots+A_0^{-(k-3)}+A_0^{-(k-1)}}.\ \ (**)
$$

Letting $c\to 1$, $A_0\to 1$ as well.  In this case $(**)$ becomes
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mu_k<\mu_0) = \frac{1}{k},
$$
which can also be found by using the optional stopping theorem with
the martingale $T_n$.  Dividing this into $(**)$ gives
$$
\mathbb{E}[c^{\mu_k}\mid \mu_k < \mu_0]
= k {A_0-A_0^{-1}\over A_0^k-A_0^{-k}},
$$
so the answer is 
$$
\sum_{k\ge 1} k {A_0-A_0^{-1}\over A_0^k-A_0^{-k}}.
$$

Comment: Nice the idea of using the optional stopping theorem! However, in (*), shouldn't the second term in the right hand side contain $c^{μ_0}$ instead of $c^{μ_k}$?

Comment: Yes, it should.  I corrected this mistake.