# Simple random walk conditioning on non-return

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, random-walk, markov-process

Consider a simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, $(S_t)_{t \geq 0}$, with $S_0=0$. Let $k$ and $j$ be two positive integers. Let $P_{k,j}$ be the probability that the walker hits the vertex $k$ *for the first time* in $j$ steps, conditioning that this happens before returning to the origin.

Namely, let $\tau_k$ be the hitting time of the vertex $k$ and let $\tau^+$ be the return time to the origin,  $P_{k,j} := P(\tau_k=j \, | \, \tau_k<\tau^+)$.

**Question:** Let $c$ be a positive constant $c<1$. Is there a way to rewrite the following expression in a nicer form? $$\sum\limits_{k \geq 1} \sum\limits_{j\geq 1} P_{k,j} \, c^{j-1}$$

Observe that $ P_{k,j}>0$ iff $j \geq k$.

Comment: Just for clarity: Is $P_{k,j}$ the probability the walk hits $k$ for the *first time* in $j$ steps (without returning to the origin in between)? [So that later hits of state $k$ don't count...]

Comment: I have clarified in the text. I meant the probability that the walk hits $k$ for the first time in $j$ steps.

Comment: Question: Is there a known closed form just for the quantities $P_{k,j}$? If so that might be a useful thing to include for anyone trying to solve the question you raise.

Comment: What do you mean for "closed" form? Do you mean rewriting $P_{k,j}$ as a function of some coefficients with lower indexes?

Comment: If in terms of lower indexes, that's like e.g. the Fibonacci series definition (it recurses to lower values). That would be of course quite good here and I haven't come up with any way to do it recursively. By closed form I would mean something even more hard to get (in general) such as a simple formula like $P_{k,j}=2^{-(k+j)},$ which is clearly wrong but has the feature that it would calculate the value directly from $k,j$ without referring to lower values.

Comment: This is the same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889175/conditional-return-time-of-simple-random-walk).